# Display a hard line gradient in Highcharts pie chart

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to use highcharts to generate a Pie/Donut chart that has an inner ring highlighted that's basically the color of the plot point, but lightened.  Something like the below.

[image: Example Pie Chart]

I've tried using the linear gradient to get something similar, but I can't quite figure it out. Does anyone know which property I would need to edit in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution seems to be adding another pie series with the same data, but also with a smaller size and different colors. For example:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'pie'
  },
  series: [{
    innerSize: '70%',
    size: '100%',
    data: [{
      y: 5,
      color: '#1d1c32'
    }, {
      y: 25,
      color: '#3e91ff'
    }]
  }, {
    linkedTo: ':previous',
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    innerSize: '85%',
    size: '70%',
    data: [{
      y: 5,
      color: '#8e8e99'
    }, {
      y: 25,
      color: '#68c8ff'
    }]
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kjrxawt1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie